# BV function decomposition derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, bounded-variation

Let $f$ be a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. I know that
$$f = f_+ - f_-,$$
where $f_+$ and $f_-$ are both increasing, and that one such decomposition is obtained by taking
$$f_{\pm}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(T_f(a,x) \pm f(x),$$
where $T_f(a,x)$ is the total variation of $f$ on $[a,x]$.

Since $f_{\pm}$ are increasing, $f_{\pm}'$ exist almost everywhere. I was told that $f_+'$ and $f_-'$ have disjoint supports, i.e. if $f_+'(x) > 0$, then $f_-'(x) = 0$. However, I'm having a hard time proving this. I tried splitting it up based on whether $f'(x)$ was positive, hoping to get some sign contradiction, but this didn't work.